# Openlitespeed - Unable to load static files in production

Tags: django, django-staticfiles, openlitespeed

I am using a ubuntu server with openlite speed and cyberpanel.

I have successfully deployed my app but regarding the static files, the browser throughs an error saying 'refused to load as its MIME type....',

I have tried to include my static files in app/public/static folder and collectstatic command worked fine. but my static files are not loaded yet.

In my settings.py I have given

```
STATIC_URL = 'python/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/example.com/public_html/public/static'
```

& also tried,

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/example.com/public_html/public/static'
```

Kindly guide me to solve this issue.

Comment: If you run runserver manually, does the static file loadable?

Comment: Sorry! It is also not working

Comment: Then you might want to fix the Django settings first.

Answer (score 0):

Here is you location path ...

You need to install WinCP then go to this path /usr/local/ ...